# storing and accessing globals in angular

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, what is the best way to store information that is needed by each page of an app?

In my case, I would like to store the name of my app, `appTitle = "my app"`, and would like this to be accessible on all pages of my app through `{{ appTitle }}`.

I tried putting `var appTitle = "my app";` into app.js, but that doesn't work.

Do I need to make a service for it and inject that into every single controller, or is there a better way?

Comment: Service would be the best way. You can also use a $rootScope or a single parent controller with properties set on its scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **constants**, but make sure that your value is really a constant like in your question.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.constant('APP_TITLE', 'my app');
```

It can be injected into your applications modules, controllers, services, etc.

```
myApp.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope', 'APP_TITLE', function($scope, APP_TITLE) {
    $scope.pageTitle = APP_TITLE;
}]);
```

You can also use **value** based on $provide. To learn more check the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#value) or in more details in [this blog post](http://iffycan.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html)